# prevent the insertion of a newline or linebreak or a tab in table cells in googlesheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to prevent the insertion of a line break in table cells with the following script in appscript with an onEdit(e) function:

```
var newValue = e.range.getValue().replaceAll('\n', ', ').replaceAll('\t', ', ');
e.range.setValue(newValue)
```

But if I drag and drop one row onto another to change the order of the rows, it triggers the script and affects the same value in all cells in the row.
Is there another way to prevent the insertion of a newline or a tab in table cells?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the script works fine except that when you change the cell order it behaves in a different way than the expected one, correct?

Comment: yes it is with this undesirable side effect

Answer (score 1):

I found a parade which is to avoid the first column which was already treated elsewhere and the chain triggering phenomenon does not happen again.

```
else if (editedColumn >1) { var newValue = e.range.getValue().replaceAll ( '\n' , ', ').replaceAll ( '\t' , ', '); 
e.range.setValue(newValue)
}
```